# Z3 taking too long for a non-linear real formula

Tags: z3py

Why does it take an unspecified large time for Z3 to solve the following Non-linear real formula? It instantly solves it if the first constraint changes for < 0 to  > 0.

**The formula:**

```
s.add (0.9993612667+0.0014*x^2+0.0014*y^2+0.0014*z^2-0.0023*x^2*y^2-0.0023*x^2*z^2-0.0023*y^2*z^2+0.0010*x^4*y^2+0.0011*x^2*y^4+0.0011*x^3*y^2*z+0.0011*x^4*z^2+0.0034*x^2*y^2*z^2+0.0011*x*y^3*z^2+0.0010*y^4*z^2+0.0011*x^2*y*z^3+0.0010*x^2*z^4+0.0011*y^2*z^4 < 0,x>=-1,x<=-0.1,y>=-1,y>=-0.1,z>=-1,z<=-0.1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have sorted out the problem by running an iterative loop on the ranges of x,y and z.That means,instead of asking Z3 to solve the problem for the whole ranges of x,y,z, i used partitioning of these ranges instead, and iteratively found the sat/unsat of the inequality.